# jQuery delegate optimization

Tags: jquery, optimization, refactoring

what is the best way to optimize the following snippets that uses delegate()?

```
jQuery('.menu').delegate('li.gallery', 'hover', function () { jQuery(this).children('.submenu').toggleClass('hide show'); });
jQuery('.menu').delegate('li.interior', 'hover', function () { jQuery(this).children('.submenu').toggleClass('hide show'); });
jQuery('.menu').delegate('li.exterior', 'hover', function () { jQuery(this).children('.submenu').toggleClass('hide show'); });


<li class="gallery"> 
                    <span>gallery</span> 
                    <ul class="submenu hide"> 
                        <li class="interior"> 
                            <a href="/gallery/interior">Interior</a> 
                            <ul class="submenu hide"> 
                                <li><a href="/gallery/interior?gallery=master-bedroom">Master Bedroom</a></li> 
                                <li><a href="/gallery/interior?gallery=living-room">Living Room</a></li> 
                                <li><a href="/gallery/interior?gallery=dining-room">Dining Room</a></li> 
                                <li><a href="/gallery/interior?gallery=kitchen">Kitchen</a></li> 
                                <li><a href="/gallery/interior?gallery=bathroom">Bathroom</a></li> 
                                <li><a href="/gallery/interior?gallery=foyer">Foyer</a></li> 
                                <li><a href="/gallery/interior?gallery=study">Study</a></li> 
                                <li><a href="/gallery/interior?gallery=sunroom">Sunroom</a></li>                                
                                <li><a href="/gallery/interior?gallery=guest-room">Guest Room</a></li>                                                              
                            </ul> 
                        </li> 
                        <li class="exterior"> 
                            <a href="/gallery/exterior">Exterior</a> 
                            <ul class="submenu hide"> 
                                <li><a href="/gallery/exterior?gallery=landscapes">Landscape</a></li> 
                                <li><a href="/gallery/exterior?gallery=gardens">Gardens</a></li> 
                                <li><a href="/gallery/exterior?gallery=cottages">Cottages</a></li> 
                                <li><a href="/gallery/exterior?gallery=entry-driveway">Entry/Driveway</a></li>                                                                                              
                            </ul> 
                        </li>                       
                    </ul> 
                </li>
```

Comment: what are you optimizing for? readability? speed? extensibility?

Comment: readability and speed. no intent to scale.

Comment: Including `.menu` would be a start.

Comment: @peter, you can take my word for it that the above is inside ul.menu :) the original code works, i just wanted to streamline it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [multiple selector (`,`)](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) in the [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) selector parameter.

However, due to [what I would consider a bug in how `.delegate()` works](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L989) (off `mouseover`/`mouseout`, which fires when entering a child) I'd steer clear it it for now and bind directly, like this:

```
jQuery('.menu').find('li.gallery, li.interior, li.exterior').hover(function () {
  jQuery(this).children('.submenu').toggleClass('hide show'); 
});
```

Comment: i thought so too, but when i get i hover over the submenu, the first toggle triggers again. i added the markup above.

Comment: @matt - Which version of jQuery are you using? `hover` wasn't added correctly until recently.

Comment: @nick 1.4.2, i think the only version with delegate.

Comment: @matt - 1.4.3 made some changes here, just for kicks try 1.4.3?

Comment: @nick yeah it's the same. when hover over the child the parent is getting toggled.

Comment: @matt - I see the issue you're having, it's due to the way `.live()` maps to `mouseneter` and `mouseleave` events, one moment.

Comment: @nick, indeed which is why i choose delegate and not live.

Comment: @matt - `.delegate()` uses `.live()` underneath, so it's the same issue, you can see the code here: http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L930

Comment: @nick oh wow, thanks. do you suggest an alternative technique?

Comment: @matt - not at the moment...the jQuery core guys need to fix this one, then the original answer is what I'd go with.